# Can my friends see me if I play games on a different server?

Tags: battle.net

I have friends on Americas server in the battlenet app, if I play on Europe server, can people see me playing games? With and/or without the launcher being open.

I know when playing Overwatch for example on Europe server, my social tab is empty. So I think no one can see me from the Americas server but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're playing on another regions server, you friends will not be able to see what game you are playing, however you will appear to be `online` in the launcher (and they will be able to message you).

So if you're playing on European servers, and your friends all play on US servers, they will just appear as `online` (or `busy`/`away` if that's what they set themselves too), and you will just appear as `online` to them too.

Comment: This seems to be the more accurate answer, I mistook was the OP was asking